# Print one column of integers into multiple columns

Tags: java, multiple-columns

I would like to take a data file containing 9 numbers in a single column and print out 3 columns containing 3 numbers.

I have loaded the file but can only print a single column. Not sure what to do.

```
Integer[] Array = new Integer[9];
         int i = 0;   

for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
    System.out.printf("%d\n",Array[x]);
```

Comment: What are you learning in your class, conditionals or the mod operator?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Array.length; x += 3) {
   System.out.printf("%d %d %d\n", Array[x], Array[x+1], Array[x+2]);
}
```

Comment: what would I do if I want to add more numbers. I'm just trying to understand how the format works.

Comment: It is the same `for` loop, but the increment is 3 instead of 1. The `printf` prints 3 values starting from index `x`. This will work, as long  the `length` of the `Array` is dividable by 3... (EG: 12, 15 or 33...)

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse through the loop and then number of column you want print them in single line and print newline once you got total column.

```
final int COLUMN =3; // define total number of column you want.

for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
   System.out.print(arr[x] +" ");

   if((x+1)%COLUMN == 0)
      System.out.println();
}
```